# How does one share code among AWS Lambdas

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I am using Go with my AWS Lambdas, there are functions and code blocks that are being used by multiple lambdas. AFAIK I may utilize Lambda Layers; however, as stated in "[Is lambda layers compatible with Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53960985/is-lambda-layers-compatible-with-go)", I doubt they are compatible. I know the compiled sizes for the binaries aren't much, but I am looking for the best practice.

***TLDR: How should one handle the shared code blocks among AWS Lambda functions?***

Comment: Not sure if anything has changed from this: [amazon web services - Is lambda layers compatible with Go? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53960985/is-lambda-layers-compatible-with-go)